# Calculate Average Rate of Change for a Set of Points

Tags: regression

I have two lists containing X/Y values which are used to plot points on a graph. The X-values are always sequential (1, 2, 3, 4...) but the Y values can vary.

For example:

```
var x = new List<int>(new[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7});
var y = new List<int>(new[] {0, 3, 7, 12, 14, 15, 17, 19});
var avgY = // What goes here?
```

With these values (the Y-values being more important in this case), how can I calculate the <s>average rate of change</s> linear regression line so that I can plot another "average" line (or "prediction" line if we were to extend the graph)?

Comment: It's called 'Linear regression'. After quick googling found a [link](http://dynamicnotions.blogspot.com/2009/05/linear-regression-in-c.html) that should give you everything you need

Comment: There are a lot of possible answers - have you looked into keywords / topics like curve fitting, splines, derivatives, extrapolation?

Comment: For extending the line, would there be data points in this area? Or are you talking about extending the line past your data points?

Answer (score 3):

You should start out with linear regression, and see if that gives you what you want. Unfortunately C# doesn't make linear regression *particularly* easy, but have a browse around some statistics packages and see if you can find one that looks easy to use.

I took advantage of R's quick modelling capabilities to do a linear regression with your data, to see if this is the kind of thing you're after:

```
x = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
y = c(0,3,7,12,14,15,17,19)
model = lm(y ~ x)
plot(x,y)
abline(coef(model))
```

which gives the following output. Is this the kind of thing you want?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

@ChrisTaylor has provided the basic answer to your question.  I just want to add another detail.  You ask, "how can I calculate the... linear regression line so that I can plot... [the] "prediction" line if we were to extend the graph?"  Doing this is called *extrapolation*, and it is generally considered to be a very dangerous practice.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis#Interpolation_and_extrapolation) for a simple overview of the topic.